# how can i use the result from a javascript function like the 'post' method of my html forms?

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers, forms

I'm using the post method of HTML forms to send back user input requests to the perl file that writes [my page](http://www.geos.ed.ac.uk/~s0825955/cgi-bin/maps7.pl). My question relates to the lat and long search boxes with on the part with the blue background. I've added the code from [this example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/click.html) to my map that introduces a function where the lat/long of a mouse click flash up on click events.

Is there a way that I could integrate this function with my forms? Would I be able to

a) add a button of the form that turns this function on and off? (so that not every click searches the database)

and

b) employ a post method, or something similar to send the coordinates derived from the click back to my perl file?

this is the relevant javacript:

```
OpenLayers.Control.Click = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, 
{
    defaultHandlerOptions: 
    {
        'single': true,
        'double': false,
        'pixelTolerance': 0,
        'stopSingle': false,
        'stopDouble': false
    },
    initialize: function(options) 
    {
        this.handlerOptions = OpenLayers.Util.extend({}, this.defaultHandlerOptions);
        OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments); 
        this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Click(this, 
        {
            'click': this.trigger
        }
        , this.handlerOptions);
    }, 
    trigger: function(e) 
    {
        var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy);
        alert("You clicked near " + lonlat.lat + " N, " +
                                  + lonlat.lon + " E");
    }
});
```

then in the map init I also use

```
var click = new OpenLayers.Control.Click();
map.addControl(click);
click.activate();
```

the `html` form is like this:

```
<form action='maps7.pl' method='post'>
    Latitude: <input type="float" name="lat"><br>
    Longitude: <input type="float" name="long"><br>
    <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="What maps are here?"><br>
    OR<br>
    Place Name: <input type="text" name="place"><br><br>
</form>
```

I currently run the query results using `perl dbi`, using this code to save them as variables:

```
$cgi = new CGI;

for $key ($cgi->param()) 
{
    $input{$key} = $cgi->param($key);
}

$searchseries = $input{series};
$slat = $input{lat};
$slong = $input{long};
```

So I want the function to be able to change `$slat` and `$slong` or form as new variables if need be.

Comment: Please post the relevant bits of HTML and JavaScript here so that future visitors can refer to them, thanks.

Comment: `< form` should be `<form`

Answer (score 0):

You should grab the latitude and logitude via JavaScript and set the value attribute of the form inputs.
Set an id in each of your inputs so you may select them via JavaScript, you could use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/val/) or plain JS to achieve that.
Ideally the user should be able to input coords manually and via mouse click. It is also useful to provide some visual feedback by drawing some marker at clicked position.